# How to run commands in CLI with Railway.app

Tags: django, deployment, command-line-interface

I have Django project deployed to Railway.app. I've installed Railway CLI, but can't understand how to run `python manage.py makemigrations` and so on in its CLI to make Django runnig.

My laptop is running Windows 10 Home.

Ho do I?

UPDATE. Some results from the answers:

In settings.py use Railway's DB. In this case you don't need to run CLI commands via Railway CLI, you may use local and it will affect the Railway's DB.

1. In case you are using dev DB, that is different from Railway's linked to project.
2. `railway login`
3. `railway link your_railway's_project_Id`
4. `railway status` to check whether you are in the right project
5. `railway run python manage.py createsuperuser`
6. This will affect Railways's DB

`railway run python manage.py collectstatic` `make migrations` `migrate` still don't run on remote server.

In `Procfile` I used code:

```
web: python manage.py migrate && gunicorn project_name.wsgi
```

Answer (score 2):

you can do that by using `railway run (command to be executed)`

for example to create a superuser, use
`railway run python manage.py createsuperuser`

Check out [this article](https://dev.to/mr_destructive/django-postgresql-deployment-on-railway-app-d54)

PS: Ensure you are in the same directory as that of the production because it will run both on local and production environment.

Comment: I did, but, it would run on local, not remote project.

Comment: I think you should check your database connection then. Make sure it has the production details

Comment: I just checked now and figured that you actually need to be in the same repo as your development environment. It mirrors your local environment with the production environment. So when you run commands with railway run (command), It runs on both local and production.

Comment: I checked database connection and it helped with `railway run python manage.py createsuperuser`, but `railway run python manage.py collectstatic` runs only locally

Comment: Unfortunately, that's how it's works. Alternatively, you can set the collectstatic command in the procfile.

Comment: It's pretty asinine that you can't just SSH into a service on this platform

Answer (score 1):

So should run IN YOUR PROJECT REPOSITORY :

- `runway link` -> Then select your project
- `runway run <your command>`